# Regex trouble, capture until find space or endline

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to capture the following match:

> "url: https://www.anysite/anything"

But sometime the string comes:

> "url: https://www.anysite/anything another word"

But i just only want to match

> "url: https://www.anysite/anything"

whether or not the "another word" comes.

So, my logic is capture until find the first space after the url address, or end of string.
My REGEX IN PHP is:

```
preg_match("/(Url|url)(\:|\b)(\s\b|\b).+(\s|$)/",$linestring,$url_string);
```

But it always bring the "another word" too, instead of bring only until space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` is greedy unless the quantifier is made ungreedy with a `?` or the `U` modified.

```
(Url|url)(\:|\b)(\s\b|\b).+?(\s|$)
```

Your actually can simplify it a bit further:

```
[Uu]rl(?::|\b)\s?\b.+?(?:\s|$)
```

If you want the URL bit capture the `.+?` with `()`.

```
[Uu]rl(?::|\b)\s?\b(.+?)(?:\s|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/urq2fM/2/

Answer (score 1):

One way to capture until the first space is to use `\S+`, which matches any sequence of one or more non-space characters:

```
url:?\s*(\S+)
```

By using the `i` flag we can avoid having to test for `Url` or `url` or `URL` etc. We can use `preg_replace` to simplify usage, replacing the string with just the captured group:

```
$url = preg_replace('/url:?\s*(\S+).*/i', '$1', $string);
```

e.g.

```
$strings = array("url: https://www.anysite/anything", 
                 "url: https://www.anysite/anything another word");

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $url = preg_replace('/url:?\s*(\S+).*/i', '$1', $string);
    echo "$url\n";
}
```

Output:

```
https://www.anysite/anything
https://www.anysite/anything
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/LfnIk)